# Has anyone ever beaten (or found a walkthrough) for the Ray's Maze game series (early B&W 1990s Mac Worldbuilder text adventures)

Tags: rays-maze

[Ray's Maze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray%27s_Maze) and its sequels "Another Fine Mess" and "A Mess O'Trouble" were circulated on mail-order 3.5" floppy disk shareware subscriptions for Mac in the early 1990s.

These are text-based adventure games with static black-and-white images accompanying each map position (sometimes clickable, although I think all click-based actions have corresponding text verbs). I was never able to beat them as a kid.

It's possible to play the old Mac System 6 games through emulators. I was able to play through "Another Fine Mess" (I suspect missing some of the side "quests") but got lost (exhausted) by the other titles. I also believe a hint book exists for "A Mess O'Trouble", but this falls short of a full walk-/through/solution key. I've not found similar for the original "Ray's Maze".

Short of dumping and reverse-engineering the game binary, I'll probably never know the solution to all the puzzles. Has anyone alive successfully played through these titles (and solved all the puzzles therein?). Are the solutions known/documented anywhere?

Comment: And the prophecies told that someday a brave soul would came and finally defeat the forgotten quest the ancients elders left incomplete. Thou are that hero now. Go now, and take heart for your journey will be a difficult one, but great glory will await you at the end. Travel, see things no one saw before, become the witness of the path to the stars, bravely tracing the steps for the ones to follow. Your name will be always remembered in the halls of history as the one who inscribed the truth in the lost lands of GameFAQS.

Comment: I mean—yes—but I have no idea what item/verb I'm supposed to use to get past the lava monster on lava mountain :P